# Lightbox analog for HTML data

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I need some analog of LightBox for HTML loaded via AJAX. And it should work in IE6 :)

I believe there is a bunch of plugins. I prefer most crossbrowser and easiest in setting. So share your expirience, please!

I'll store them here, for our children (I'll add more from comments):

- http://fancybox.net/ (IE6 works)
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html (IE6 didn't work)
- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ (IE6 works)
- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ (IE6+)

Comment: Are you asking a question? It looks like you already have the answers.

Comment: I am asking to share user's expirience and links to other lightboxes. Also it can became a comunity wiki. Because it is quite popular question. It is good idea to store expirience in one place. And practically I need to choose one of this lightboxes to use in my project.

Comment: [Even Microsoft is sick of IE6](http://www.theie6countdown.com/). Are you _sure_ you can't move to a better browser?

Comment: That's not about me, that's about my users (it is Russian countryside actually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as there is no any complete answer

- http://fancybox.net/ (IE6 works)
- http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html (IE6 didn't work)
- http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ (IE6 works)
- http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/ (IE6+)

Answer (score 1):

A project I worked on about 7 months ago used fancybox for displaying HTML loaded by AJAX.  It worked well, and we never really had any complaints with it.

Fortunately, we didn't have to support IE6.